# rootfs 100% full debian

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, raspberry-pi

I have a problem with full rootfs on Debian (on RPi). I noticed I can't start mysql server with error full partition. I tried looking for space hoggers with `ncdu`.
It all appeared suddenly and I have no idea what to do. I can't even run `apt-get remove`.
Thanks for your help!

```
rootfs            3731272 3714888        0 100% /
/dev/root         3731272 3714888        0 100% /
devtmpfs           242988       0   242988   0% /dev
tmpfs               49452     236    49216   1% /run
tmpfs                5120       0     5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda1        14872964 3144768 10949652  23% /media/usb0
/dev/sdb1        14872964 3355940 10738480  24% /media/usb1
/dev/sda1        14872964 3144768 10949652  23% /media/usb2
tmpfs               98900       0    98900   0% /run/shm
tmpfs               98900       0    98900   0% /tmp
```

`sudo du / -h --max-depth=1`

```
94M     /opt
5,2M    /bin
333M    /var
109M    /lib
1,8G    /usr
0       /tmp
6,3M    /sbin
16K     /lost+found
8,0K    /boot
4,0K    /selinux
192K    /home
4,0K    /usb
236K    /run
0       /proc
4,0K    /mnt
6,7M    /etc
9,1G    /media
4,0K    /srv
0       /sys
40K     /root
0       /dev
12G     /
```

`du --one-file-system --max-depth=1 --human-readable /`

```
94M     /opt
5,2M    /bin
333M    /var
109M    /lib
1,8G    /usr
0       /tmp
6,3M    /sbin
16K     /lost+found
8,0K    /boot
4,0K    /selinux
192K    /home
4,0K    /usb
0       /run
0       /proc
4,0K    /mnt
6,7M    /etc
36K     /media
4,0K    /srv
0       /sys
40K     /root
0       /dev
2,3G    /
```

Comment: Please run `du --one-file-system --max-depth=1 --human-readable /` instead to get meaningful information.

Comment: @DanielB Added to post

Comment: Well now that doesn’t exactly sum up to 3.5 GiB, so something is wrong. You may need to repair the filesystem. Please run `e2fsck -n` on your root partition. **Do not run it without `-n` while the filesystem is mounted.**

Comment: @DanielB How can I unmount rootfs? Thank you. I tried umount -l and it unmounted but fsck wasn't working

Comment: You need an OS not running from this partition, either on your Pi or simply on a PC. However, you don’t need to unmount it with `-n`. Though it won’t fix anything, of course.

Comment: @DanielB I got this error: e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could this be a zero-length partition?